# Handling ASIHTTPRequest Multiple Requests

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsurlconnection, asihttprequest

I've been struggling with this problem for over a week. And I really need some help.

I am using `ASIHTTPRequest` to handle three different download requests. The first download request will download from an online .txt file a timestamp. According to that timestamp, it must process how the application will launch.

It will check if a timestamp has been previously saved in `NSUserDefaults`, if not then this is the first time the app is launched and it will download a JSON feed (using `ASIHTTPRequest`) and then parse it into Core Data.

If the stored timestamp matches the online one, then nothing happens since the data is up to date.

If the stored timestmap is older than the online timestamp, then the database will be cleared and redownloaded.

My problem is that in `ASIHTTPRequest`, before `requestFinished` gets executed, `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` gets executed to the end. Now in the beginning of `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, I ask `ASIHTTPRequest` to download the online timestamp. Before `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is over, I need to have the online timestamp downloaded and ready to be use. How would I do that? Problem with `ASIHTTPRequest` is that it starts executing after `application:DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is over.

Comment: Why do you think you need to have the onilnetimestamp ready to use before application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is over? Fundamentally that is impossible to achieve, so you need to restructure your code.

Comment: To know whether to download and replace the database or not. used blocks and mutlithreading and it works perfectly now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without some code to look at, our answers have to be fairly general. But it sounds to me like you need to change your startup flow completely.

If it's important that your http requests happen in order, you need to call them in order--nested in each other's completion delegate methods. You can use ASIHTTPRequest's `.userInfo` field to identify the different types of request you're firing.

Your `didFinishLaunching` method should just do enough to get your first request started (and maybe bring up a "loading" view), then the rest of the app launching work needs to be done in the various `requestDidFinish` methods.

If you're in control of the website side of things too, you might see how much of this work you can offload to the server code. I prefer to do my work on the biggest iron I can find, which means I usually do my data manipulation in my web app, and just send the results out to the phone.

EDIT: Here's some code to describe what I mean by "nested in each other's completion methods". Note that I just typed this right here, so don't just copy and paste this and expect anything like sensible behavior.

```
// inside didFinishLaunching
ASIHTTPRequest *myInitialRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:myNSURL];
myInitialRequest.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"initial" forKey:@"type"];
myInitialRequest.delegate = self;
[myInitialRequest startAsynchronous];
// and then NOT other setup stuff that depends on this data.


-requestDidFinish:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    if ([[request.userInfo objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"initial"]) {
        //you just used the userinfo field to differentiate this from other requests
        //do whatever here, and then make your next request HERE.

        ASIHTTPRequest *nextRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:myNextURL];
        nextRequest.delegate = self;
        nextRequest.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"next" forKey:@"type"];
        [nextRequest startAsynchronous];
    }
    if ([[request.userInfo objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"next"]) {
        // so now you know this is your "next" type request coming back to you.

        // ... so do whatever you do with this, and then HERE do the rest of your
        // app setup and launch business.
    }
}
```

So you set up a request with a userInfo field that identifies it, and then differentiate the handling of its response based on that field. That's basic to using more than one ASIHTTPRequest in a view controller anyway.

And then your next request is based on the response of the first one--you're launching a second request after learning what you needed to learn from the first one's response content.

By the way, you can also specify the completion handler method, or use the block interface to specify what ASIHTTPRequest does on completion. But I think loading your requests up with identifying userInfo fields and then handling your responses all in one place is the cleanest approach.

Comment: Hi Dan, Again, I don't understand what you and @Jim mean by **completion delegate method**. What is nested in each other's completion delegate methods. What is that?

Comment: Well sort of, except that it takes a NSDictionary. But you can use it the same way--stash some info in it to use later to find the thing you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it that way.  The problem you are having is that the request is asynchronous.  You can't change it to be synchronous because if there are any network delays, iOS will terminate the app for taking too long to load.

Put the rest of the application startup code in the completion handler of the request.  When the request is completed, it will call the completion handler.

Comment: What do you mean by the completion handler of the request? My start up code calls a couple of requests. So putting that code in `requestDidFinish` will not work since the code will end up calling `requestDidFinish`. ASIHTTPRequest only has two methods: `requestFinished`, which processes the actual request, and `requestFailed`. If you still don't understand, would you like me to add my code on top?

Comment: Jim means the 'requestFinished' method on your delegate when he says 'completion handler'.

Comment: I don't think that should work because my code calls more requests, therefore it will keep calling itself if I put more request calling in the completion method. Am I right?

Comment: You can branch in your completion handler, use blocks to provide different completion handlers for each request, or use a queue.

Comment: @Jim Do I have to use GCD with blocks? Sorry but I never used multithreading before I am learning.

Comment: @Nayefc, no, you don't have to use GCD, and it's not multithreading.  See [A Short Practical Guide to Blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/_index.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009758) for details.

Answer (score 0):

As Jim rightly pointed, the issue is with asynchronous request to your server. "application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" method continues its execution after making a asynchronous server call. Your server request might take some time and by that time "application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" method might be out of its loop. So only solution for this to make a synchronous call to the server and make "application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" to wait until server respond back with the response and then continue executing the next instruction. You can achieve this using the "startSynchronous" method of ASIHTTPRequest.

Comment: Exactly. Let me clarify one thing. In your case, synchronous call will be executed in application main thread. So "applicationDidFiinishLaunnchingWithOptions" can execute the next request only after the current request is processed. Whereas asynchronous request uses a separate thread for execution.. Since "applicationDidFiinishLaunnchingWithOptions" method is called in main thread, after making a asynchronous call(separate thread) it continues its execution with the main thread. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: Calling startSyncronous from applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions does not sound like a good idea to me. It will mean the application will lock up on launch (and as Jim already said get killed) if the server is slow to respond. It's likely to be rejected by the app store testing team too.

Comment: @JosephH so why do you suggest then in my case?

Comment: You need to do what Jim & Dan are suggesting.

Comment: I'm working on a navigation controller-based app with a similar requirement. The way I handle it is to add an asynchronous http request from the app delegate that fires on startup, and displays a "loading" MBProgressHUD. If the request fails or times out, a "This app requires network connectivity" view is sent to the navigation controller as a modal popup (thereby overlapping whatever the current view is).